# How to connect distro elasticsearch service to another service defined in docker compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elasticsearch-opendistro

hi i want to connect to Elasticsearch inside my app which is defined as "cog-app" service in docker-compose.yml along with ditsro elasticsearch and kibana

i am not able to connect to elasticsearch when i run docker file, can you please tell me how i can connect elasticsearch service to app service

i have defined elasticsearch in cog-app service, and im getting connection failure with elasticsearch

```
version: "3"
services:
  cog-app:
    image: app:2.0
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "7111:7111"
    environment:
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
      - LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
      - CONTAINER_NAME=app
    volumes:
      - /home/developer/app:/app

  odfe-node1:
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.13.2
    container_name: odfe-node1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=odfe-cluster
      - node.name=odfe-node1
      - discovery.seed_hosts=odfe-node1,odfe-node2
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=odfe-node1,odfe-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # maximum number of open files for the Elasticsearch user, set to at least 65536 on modern systems
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - odfe-data1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
      
  odfe-node2:
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.13.2
    container_name: odfe-node2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=odfe-cluster
      - node.name=odfe-node2
      - discovery.seed_hosts=odfe-node1,odfe-node2
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=odfe-node1,odfe-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - odfe-data2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - odfe-net
  kibana:
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch-kibana:1.13.2
    container_name: odfe-kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: https://odfe-node1:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://odfe-node1:9200
    networks:
      - odfe-net

volumes:
  odfe-data1:
  odfe-data2:

networks:
  odfe-net:
```

please tell me how two services can communicate with each other

Comment: how are you trying to connect to elasticsearch inside your app? Could you share the url/string connection or a piece of code?

Comment: @usuario, i am trying to connect like this - 

es = Elasticsearch(hosts="https://admin:admin@localhost:9200",verify_certs=False)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the elasticsearch service is running in another container, `localhost` is not valid. You should use `odfe-node1:9200` as the url

Comment: es = Elasticsearch(hosts="https://admin:admin@ofde-node1:9200",verify_certs=False)
i tried this but doesnt work

Comment: any help on this?

Comment: The kibana service is using the same url (ofde-node1:9200) to connect, is it working? From networking in compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), `By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.`

Comment: yeah kibana service is running, i tried passing elasticsearch url as env variable in cog-app , that is also not working